# SQL. Possible to see each individual ID after group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

SQL question.

Is it possible to see uniqe IDs in select after a group by?

Example.

Before group by, taskid, purposecode and userid

```
ID     TaskId     Purposecode    UserId     Time
1      1          915            421        7.0
2      1          915            421        7.0
3      1          915            421        7.0
4      4          912            421        7.0
5      4          912            421        7.0
```

After group by

```
     TaskId     Purposecode    UserId     Time
       1          915            421        21.0 (uniqeID: 1,2,3)
       4          912            421        14.0 (uniqeID: 4,5)
```

I would like to see all my IDs for each individual group by. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it and there are plenty of examples in the internet and this website... next time try to search more:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, TaskId INT,Purposecode INT,UserId INT, Time Numeric(5,1))
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 1, 1, 915, 421, 7.0
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 2, 1, 915, 421, 7.0
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 3, 1, 915, 421, 7.0
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 4, 4, 912, 421, 7.0
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 5, 4, 912, 421, 7.0


SELECT TaskId, Purposecode, UserId, SUM(Time) AS Time,

    STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + CAST(T2.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        FROM @table T2
        WHERE T.Purposecode = T2.Purposecode
            AND T.TaskId = T2.TaskId
            AND T.UserId = T2.UserId
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS UniqueIDs

FROM @table AS T
GROUP BY TaskId, Purposecode, UserId
```

`STUFF` removes first comma

`FOR XML PATH` puts all rows into one